# How to do conditional aggregate based on values of another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `device_data` that looks like below

```
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                     Default                     
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                     |           |          | nextval('device_data_id_seq'::regclass)
 date           | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 packet_drop    | real                        |           |          | 
 jitter         | real                        |           |          | 
 latency        | real                        |           |          | 
 alert          | character varying(50)       |           |          |
```

It basically stores the `packet drops`, `jitter`, `latency` on a minute basis.

Now there is another column called `alert` that holds the value `HIGH`, `MEDIUM` and `LOW` based on a threshold and holds empty string   if the threshold is not met.

Now I do an hourly average on the table, my query looks like below

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', date) AS hourly,
    avg(jitter),
    avg(latency),
    avg(packet_drop)
FROM device_data
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-11-26 17:41:11' AND '2022-11-27 17:41:11'
GROUP BY hourly 
ORDER BY hourly;
```

**Output**

```
       hourly        |        avg         |        avg         |         avg         
---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------
 2022-11-26 17:00:00 |   3.52857138642243 |  2.771428568022592 |                   0
 2022-11-26 18:00:00 |  2.484615419346553 |  2.815384602546692 |                   0
 2022-11-26 19:00:00 |  2.218461540570626 |  2.723076921242934 |                   0
 2022-11-26 20:00:00 |  5.098461512992015 | 2.7076923021903405 |                   0
 2022-11-26 21:00:00 | 2.0060606116824076 | 2.6469696814363655 |                   0
 2022-11-26 22:00:00 |  5.672307815345434 |  2.810769222332881 |                   0
 2022-11-26 23:00:00 | 2.7828124976949766 |  2.893749985843897 |                   0
 2022-11-27 00:00:00 | 2.6046153992414474 | 2.8030769238105187 |                   0
 2022-11-27 01:00:00 |  3.846031717837803 | 2.8333333200878568 |                   0
 ...
(25 rows)
```

Next I do an hourly average on the table with additional column `alert`, so my query looks something like below

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', date) as hourly,
    avg(jitter),
    avg(latency),
    avg(packet_drop),
    alert from device_data
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-11-26 17:41:11' AND '2022-11-27 17:41:11'
GROUP BY hourly, alert
ORDER BY hourly;
```

**Output**

```
       hourly        |        avg         |        avg         |         avg         | alert 
---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------
 2022-11-26 17:00:00 | 1.2649999938905239 |  2.755000001192093 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 17:00:00 |  48.79999923706055 | 3.0999999046325684 |                   0 | MEDIUM
 2022-11-26 18:00:00 |  2.484615419346553 |  2.815384602546692 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 19:00:00 |  2.218461540570626 |  2.723076921242934 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 20:00:00 | 2.6603174461495307 |     2.695238092589 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 20:00:00 |  106.5999984741211 | 3.0999999046325684 |                   0 | HIGH
 2022-11-26 20:00:00 |  57.20000076293945 | 3.0999999046325684 |                   0 | MEDIUM
 2022-11-26 21:00:00 | 2.0060606116824076 | 2.6469696814363655 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 22:00:00 | 2.8349206649831364 |  2.793650784189739 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 22:00:00 |  95.05000305175781 |  3.350000023841858 |                   0 | HIGH
 2022-11-26 23:00:00 | 2.7828124976949766 |  2.893749985843897 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-27 00:00:00 |  2.132812526775524 |           2.796875 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-27 00:00:00 |  32.79999923706055 |  3.200000047683716 |                   0 | LOW
 2022-11-27 01:00:00 |  1.849999995962266 |  2.822580631702177 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-27 01:00:00 |  127.5999984741211 |                3.5 |                   0 | HIGH
 ...
(35 rows)
```

As you can see in my second query, some of the rows have duplicate timestamps like `2022-11-26 17:00:00`, `2022-11-26 20:00:00` and so on.

I understand that when averaging out the columns, in the case of `alert` column, it encounters multiple values be it empty string along with some `HIGH`, `MEDIUM` or `LOW` strings or some other combinations resulting in multiple rows for the same timestamp.

**Requirement**

What I want is to simply average out the values (initially ignoring the `alert` column values) and then check for `HIGH` string in the `alert` column for that particular hour (I am doing hourly average). If the string is present, simply assign `HIGH` for that row in the `alert` column. If no `HIGH` string found, just assign empty string   for that row in the `alert` column. Something like below

**Expected output**

```
       hourly        |        avg         |        avg         |         avg         | alert 
---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------
 2022-11-26 17:00:00 |  3.52857138642243   |  2.771428568022592 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 18:00:00 |  2.484615419346553  |  2.815384602546692 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 19:00:00 |  2.218461540570626  |  2.723076921242934 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 20:00:00 |  5.098461512992015  | 2.7076923021903405 |                   0 |  HIGH
 2022-11-26 21:00:00 |  2.0060606116824076 | 2.6469696814363655 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-26 22:00:00 |  5.672307815345434  |  2.810769222332881 |                   0 |  HIGH
 2022-11-26 23:00:00 |  2.7828124976949766 |  2.893749985843897 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-27 00:00:00 |  2.6046153992414474 | 2.8030769238105187 |                   0 | 
 2022-11-27 01:00:00 |  3.846031717837803  | 2.8333333200878568 |                   0 |  HIGH
 ...
(25 rows)
```

I thought of only targeting rows containing `HIGH` value in `alert` column by doing something like `where alert = 'HIGH'`, but then it will drop other rows and affect my average calculation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an aggregate function for the column 'alert', as well. Since you want to only bring up a certain value, you can use a conditional expression inside the aggregate, like this:

```
select 
     date_trunc('hour', date) as hourly
   , avg(jitter)
   , avg(latency)
   , avg(packet_drop)
   , coalesce(MAX(case when alert='HIGH' then 'HIGH' end),'') as alert 
from device_data 
where date between '2022-11-26 17:41:11' and '2022-11-27 17:41:11' 
group by hourly order by hourly;
```

This should work, because the MAX function ignores the NULL values (all alert values other than HIGH will cause NULL result in the case expression.

Comment: Btw removed `alert` from groupby otherwise it was throwing errors since aggregate can't be grouped by.